# Content editable inline div moves when empty

Tags: css, html, alignment, inline

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nojv18wf/

```
<div>
    <div class="display">Blah blah blah?</div>
    <div class="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

<div>
    <div class="display">Blah blah blah?</div>
    <div class="input border" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Watch where the caret goes when you click on "blah blah blah."

In the first example, it jumps to *before the blah blah blah*, until you type text, and then it appears in the correct place.

In the second example, with the border, it works as it should.

How can I get the caret to appear in the correct place without adding an ugly border?

**EDIT:** This appears to be happening only in Chrome, it works normally in Firefox and even IE.

**EDIT 2:** The reason I am using inline is so that the text wraps as if it was a smooth continuation, not wrap the whole block. E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/khkurs5t/

Comment: Work fine for me, I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Ahh. I am in chrome. It does work for me in Firefox...

Comment: Why aren't you using placeholders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add a transparent border to your `input`, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/mqymo4ux/)

```
border: solid 1px transparent;
```

This will keep your text on the same line as you mentioned as well.

NOTE* Guess who doesn't like to keep text on the same line though... Yes... IE But this method does work in all other browsers. Good luck my friend!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inline-block` layout together with `min-width`.

```
.input{ display: inline-block; min-width: 1px;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nojv18wf/1/)

Comment: +1, this does work, however I am trying to make the text continue on the same line as shown: http://jsfiddle.net/khkurs5t/